# Объявление массива в массиве

Tags: lua

Пытался сделать массив доступ к которому можно получить таким способом

```
mas[1].type
mas[1].owner
mas[1].id
```

Объявил массив так

```
mas = {[1] = {[type]= "first", [owner] = "412874192", [id] = "64345734"}}
```

получаю ошибку

```
table index is nil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Квадратные скобки вокруг названий полей не нужны. С ними `type` и пр. интерпретируются как имена переменных, значения которых должны быть ключами таблицы. Поскольку таких переменных нет, то и ключи оказываются `nil`.

Кроме того, `[1]` можно пропустить. Итак:

```lua
mas = {{type= 'first', owner = '412874192', id = '64345734'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Запомните, что в lua не существует ни массивов, ни объектов, есть только таблицы. Александр дал правильный ответ, я лишь уточню, что в его ответе индекс 1 был выброшен, поскольку он был создан автоматически (если вы не задаёте никакого индекса, то создаётся числовой и итерация начинается с единицы). Но если бы здесь была не единица, а другое число, то вам всё же пришлось бы указать его в квадратных скобках, потому что имя переменной не может начинаться с числа. Так же и с другими символами:

```lua
local mas = {
  [3] = {
    ["type-/*+"] = "first",
    owner = "412874192",
    id = "64345734"
  }
}

print(mas[3]["type-/*+"])
```